# How do I determine if code snippets are working for me?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

I'm trying to learn the MVVM design pattern, using MVVM Light.  I've downloaded it, and installed it.  I've created a new WPF app, using the MVVM Light template.  Now I'm going through a tutorial I've found online on a blog.  It mentions typing a string and hitting the tab key, in order to invoke the code snippet.  What happens instead for me, is Intellisence puts in the namespace (the string of text is close to the namespace).  So, from my point of view, the code snippets aren't working at all.

Bottom line: how do I determine if code snippets are working?  What code snippets are available to me?  I'm using VS 2010 Premium with SP1.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you have seen may not be a default one: [Visual C# Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z41h7fat.aspx).

It could also be that some tool you have installed (ReSharper?) may have overridden a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> then type in `try` (for example) you will see the "try catch" code snippet appear in intelisense.

[image: Snippet]

You can tell that it is a snippet by the icon. Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice will create the following code:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception)
{               
    throw;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the Ctrl+Space key sequence.  I've tried the "try" and that works fine.  However, when I tried typing in "mvvmlocatorproperty" I got nothing, when I should have, in working with MVVM Light.  Have I done something wrong, or somehow failed to properly install MVVM Light?

Comment: Have a look in %userprofile%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Code Snippets for your snippets.